# Count number of file requests triggered

Tags: php, cakephp, apache2, debian, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible with PHP(5) or other Linux tools on an apache debian webserver to get the file requests a single http request made?
for performance reasons i would like to compare them with the cached "version" of my cake app.

non-cached that might be over 100 in some views.
cached only up to 10 (hopefully).

afaik there are 3 main file functions:
file_get_contents(), file() and the manual fopen() etc

but i cannot override them so i cannot place a logRequest() function in them.
is there any other way? attaching callbacks to functions? intercepting the file requests?

Comment: If you are only interested in how the cached version performs versus the non-cached version, simply run a profiler once with cache enabled and then again with cache disabled. That should tell you the difference. Can use Xdebug for this. If you want to do load tests, use the `ab` command.

Comment: well, in this particular case more the amount of file requests the php script needs to accomplish the final result. not only for comparison against the cached version, but also for the goal to track the views with the most file requests and trying to lower the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestion does not seems intuitive, but you can take look on [xdebug - function trace](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace)

Once you have xdebug installed and enabled, you can using all sort of configuration to save the profiling into a disk file and you can retrieve it later. Such as profiling results for different URL save into different disk file.

To monitoring file system related functions, you can do a parse of the text file(profiling results) and do a count of matchable functions (programmable or manually)

Comment: thx a lot - due to xdebug i got: 272 file_exists, 100 require, 20 include, 32 fopen for a single request of my cakephp app (home page)

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it would be to create a custom function that wraps around the one you need.

```
function custom_file_get_contents($filename) {
    $GLOBALS['file_get_contents_count']++;
    return file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

And just replace all of your calls to file_get_contents with custom_file_get_contents. This is just a rudimentary example, but you get the idea.

Side note, if you want to count how many files your script has included (or required), see [get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)

Comment: sure - but that would require my CAKE core to be modified. and that's what you would want to avoid. using a framework with a modified core would make core-updates quite difficult.

Comment: +1. Also, if you are using calls to file_get_contents with multiple arguments... you can use 'return file_get_contents(...func_get_args());' to catch and use them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xdebug to log all function calls

> Those so-called "function traces" can be a help for when you are new to an application or when you are trying to figure out what exactly is going on when your application is running. The function traces can optionally also show the values of variables passed to the functions and methods, and also return values. In the default traces those two elements are not available.

- http://www.xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I'd start with the [stream_wrapper](http://php.net/stream_wrapper) ... try to replace them with custom classes.

Comment: interesting class. i guess no one tried that before... :) at least my search didnt turn up any results on trying to count the requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pecl extention called ADB (Advanced PHP Debugger) that has tow functions that would be very useful for a cse like this - override_function() and rename_function(). You could do something like this:

```
rename_function('file_get_contents', 'file_get_contents_orig');

function file_get_contents($filename) {
    logRequest();
    return file_get_contents_orig($filename);
}
```

It looks like ADB is pretty easy to install, too.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php